# Довешивание на вопрос меток разных языков

Tags: обсуждение, метки, вопросы

Известно, что из-за многообразия различных языков программирования, так или иначе одни языки что-то заимствуют от других, некоторые и вовсе можно, хотя с некоторой натяжкой, считать подмножествами других (наиболее яркий пример, наверное, [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) и [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)). Таким образом, вопрос, заданный с меткой [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), может формально получить ответ, который будет справедлив так же и для [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

В связи с этим появился вопрос: стоит ли в таких случаях вешать на вопрос метку дополнительного языка, если ответ будет применим так же и к нему, или эта практика порочна, так как делает вопрос всё же несколько шире того, что изначально предполагал автор?

Гипотетическая ситуация: есть вопрос исключительно с меткой [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). На него пишется кем-то ответ в стиле C, и им же добавляется метка [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). Код в ответе компилируется в обоих языках.

Comment: на мой взгляд если нет однозначной уверенности, то от *навешивания* дополнительных меток *расширяющих* вопрос стоит воздержаться.

Comment: @Bald однозначной уверенности *в чём*?

Comment: однозначной уверенности в совершаемых действиях. на примере ваших меток добавление другой метки может повлиять на ответ. IMHO

Comment: @Bald может повлиять, да. Но я сделал акцент на том, что ответ применим и к исходной метке. Т.к. предложенное решение опирается на базовый функционал, доступный как в [tag:c++], так и в [tag:c].

Comment: именно это я имел ввиду говоря об *однозначной уверенности*. но все же я считаю что делать это надо осторожно

Comment: Вот бы узнать, а как много участников (кроме постоянных посетителей Меты) вообще серьезно смотрит на метки?

Comment: @alexolut вообще языки слишком разные чтобы вешать обе метки. Например, формально, использование stdio.h вместо cstdio в С++ УЖЕ ошибка, т.к. может привести к UB  при совместном использовании с классами из std::

Comment: ТС - особенно неопытный - может просто не понимать, к чему **на самом деле** относится вопрос. И это исправление меток ничем по сути не отличается от исправления текста вопроса. Почему текст вопроса можно править, а набор меток - нет?...

Comment: @Harry: Это по сути одно и то же, и проблематика тут та же самая: не изменяем ли мы при правке **суть** вопроса?

Comment: @VladD О том и говорю - править или нет текст - вопрос не встает, а править или нет тэги - почему-то вызывает бурную дискуссию...

Comment: @Harry речь не о всех тегах сейчас, а исключительно о языковых.

Comment: @alexolut А есть **принципиальная** разница?

Comment: @Harry конечно. Это расширяет тематику вопроса.

Comment: @alexolut Так же, как может сделать неудачная правка текста. Впрочем, я уже высказал свое мнение в ответе...

Comment: @Harry в ответе Вы не считаете подобную правку неудачной, если я правильно понял.

Comment: @alexolut Да, я полагаю, что это такая же правка, как и правка текста, с такой же ответственностью за корректность вносимого исправления тэгов, как и ответственность за корректность правки текста.

Comment: Очередной вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655471/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%80%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b0 - ну вот что в нем конкретно C++'ного - не считая использования `cout`, `new` и `delete`? При том, что они **не имеют никакого отношения к сути** вопроса. А вопрос мог бы точно так же быть сформулирован и для C. И ответ дать - как тут боялись - такой, что не пригодится для C++, пожалуй, невозможно...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Не стоит смешивать **разные** языки (диалекты). Это размывает вопрос.

Вопрос насколько С отличается от С++ или, например, от С++17 ..?
Могу сказать по теме которую сам знаю - аналогичный пример из мира Delphi/Pascal/PascalABC/FPC/PascalScript/SmartStudio. Добавление меток уместно только если вопрос достаточно абстрактен и базов (например как посчитать неквадратный корень). Языки (диалекты) начинают очень быстро и сильно отличаться в деталях реализации. Если вопрос затрагивает какие-то особенности, ответы уже не взаимо-заменяемы.

2. Ответы на простые вопросы многочисленны и ищутся гуглом, а не по меткам на сайте. Т.о. добавление меток на них принесет мало пользы.
3. Ответы на непростые вопросы достаточно специфичны и лишние метки им не нужны. Также, вероятно, ищущему не составит труда адаптировать решение на нужный диалект.

Если автора интересует алгоритм, тогда уместно отсутствие меток языка вовсе, или метка "любой-язык".

---

> Гипотетическая ситуация: есть вопрос исключительно с меткой c++. На него пишется кем-то ответ в стиле C, и им же добавляется метка c. Код в ответе компилируется в обоих языках.

Потом кто-то смотрит на метки и дает ответ на С. В итоге мы имеем вопрос про 1 проблему на 2 языках и ответы на 2 языках. Какой ответ отмечать верным? Причем получается, никто не спрашивает автора вопроса, какой же ответ ему нужен. А посетителям приходится разбираться, какой же из ответов правильнее и *почему*.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос примером.

Comment: про размытие безусловно согласен. Но в силу того, что галочку ставит только автор, вопрос о том, какой ответ принимать, имхо, не стоит так остро.

Comment: @alexolut галочка ставится один раз (или вовсе не ставится), а вопрос потом годами можно редактировать и "улучшать"

Comment: @Qwertiy пожалуйста не надо делать список линейным. Это противоречит (моей) авторской идее.

Comment: @Kromster, ok. Я думал, это опечатка :)

Answer (score 6):

Если вопрос задан так, что сам **вопрос** имеет смысл и для одного, и для другого языка - считаю, что такое добавление оправданно. Например, только что был вопрос

[C++ показать вторую букву из слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654295/c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0?s=2|0.0000)

Этот вопрос звучит совершенно одинаково для обоих языков, имеет один и тот же ответ в обоих языках - поэтому я добавил ему метку C. Тот, кто будет искать готовый ответ (это большая редкость, все обычно задают свой вопрос не глядя, что уже есть готового... но это уже уход в сторону от темы дискуссии) для C - может и не увидеть его, если укажет тэг именно C.

Думаю, что тэг нужен *для поиска*, и в этом смысле большее количество тэгов (но соответствующих вопросу) - лучше.

P.S. Кстати, спасибо, подсказали своим вопросом, что на упомянутый вопрос следует добавить тэги "строку" и "массив"... :)

P.P.S. Как часто вопрос, в котором применен один-единственный оператор, специфичный для C++, из-за этого формально не проходит под тэг C, хотя на самом деле суть вопроса - например, в выходе за границу массива!...

И еще одно алаверды, так сказать :)
ТС - особенно неопытный - может просто не понимать, к чему **на самом деле** относится вопрос. И это исправление меток ничем по сути не отличается от исправления текста вопроса. Почему текст вопроса можно править, а набор меток - нет?...

Comment: Более того, куча вопросов, отмеченных С++, на самом деле укладываются в Си

Comment: @avp если вопрос по C++, то он и ответ должен быть на C++, а не на общем подмножестве операторов и функций. Например, C ответ может подразумевать рукописный цикл, на C++ же в первую очередь стоит использовать алгоритмы из стандартной библиотеки. Со строками в C++ надо использовать возможности класса `std::string`, а не сишные `strcpy`/`strcat` и т.п., которые тем не менее доступны в C++, и т.д.

Comment: @alexolut Когда человек только начинает изучать язык, и в особенности, когда это изучение направляется программой/преподавателем, который хочет, чтоб человек научился сам писать алгоритмы, а не готовое соединять - такое решение может просто вредить обучению. Станок с ЧПУ позволяет творить чудеса, но если вы считаете, что напильник, скажем, больше не нужен - я с вами не соглашусь. Не понимая, как написать конкатенацию строк без библиотеки или как написать ту же, пусть медленную, сортировку вставками - получим ремесленника, который умеет только из конструктора LEGO по чертежам собирать...

Comment: @Harry в вопросе с меткой ЧПУ ответы "как сделать деталь напильником" неуместны.

Comment: @alexolut Я считаю, что в вопросе, где точно видно, что речь идет о тисках и напильниках, лучше не начинать умничать, рассказывая о ЧПУ, ориентируясь на метку и поясняя, что современные технологии таковы и таковы, а рассказать о том, что **нужно** этому человеку, подправив заодно его ошибку с меткой. На этом предлагаю дискуссию и завершить - каждый останется при своих; если же модераторы решат, что метки править не следует - они просто перекроют такую возможность.

Comment: @Harry модераторы не обладают полномочиями перекрывать возможность править метки :) если это не красные метки на Мете, конечно.

Answer (score 4):

Если позволите внести свою лепту, то я скажу следующее: некоторые люди не смотрят общий список вопросов, а смотрят вопросы только по отобранным тегам.

Представим ситуацию. Вы задали вопрос и пометили его тегом `C`. Человек, который потенциально может помочь в вопросе (быстро), просматривает только ветку `C++` (и какие-то другие теги), но не ветку с тегом `C`.

Вы же задали вопрос с тегом `C`, и в итоге получили ответ, предположим, через трое суток вместо 10 часов, так как компетентный человек в вашем вопросе, просматривающий ветку `C` (и какие-то ещё) нашёлся именно через это время.

Вывод: архитектура меток в хронологическом порядке, это, конечно, круто, но лучше не бояться излишних тегов.

Comment: Как много ```C``` я написал...

Comment: Если это сделал сам ТС, то это нормально, и его может устроить как ответ по C, так и по C++. Или некий общий вариант - код, подходящий для двух языков одновременно. Если же из тела вопроса ясно, что нужен исключительно C вариант, то метка C++ должна быть убрана с вопроса, как не соответствующая действительности. Таким образом, ситуация двояка: можно получить ответ быстрее, но при этом он будет бесполезен. Меня всё же больше интересует ситуация с довешиванием **другими участниками** (предоставляющими ответ), а не самим ТС.

Comment: @alexolut уловил суть